# Biophysics and mathematical biology landmark papers

Tags: resource-recommendations, biophysics

I am PhD student in biophysics, and I am looking for interesting theoretical papers for my personal training and for journal club presentations.

Going on journal websites and browse the thousands of references is laborious. The ideal would be a book similar to what "Landmark Papers in Cell Biology" is for biology, but for mathematical biology or biophysics.

*My interests : polymerization, phase separation, reaction diffusion, reaction systems, equilibrium or non equilibrium statistical physics, phase transitions*

Comment: Have you asked your colleagues (under the same advisor or not) for some of the more seminal papers?

Comment: I am in a bioengineering department, and no colleagues. Just my advisor and me.

Comment: Come to think of it, have you asked your advisor?

Comment: What kind of thing are you interested in within biophysics? I know of some papers about elasticity of membranes and polymers, and some non-equilibrium stat mech papers that my group has used for a journal club. Can you be more specific about your interest?

Comment: Polymerization, phase separation, reaction diffusion, reaction systems, equilibrium or non equibrium statistical physics, phase transitions

Comment: @KyleKanos : about papers? Yes he did send some

Comment: This question (v4) seems like a list question.

Answer (score 2):

In non-equilibrium stat mech, I would recommend Gavin Crooks' "Entropy production fluctuation theorem and the nonequilibrium work relation for free energy differences", in which he proves his famous theorem, and the related experimental paper by Carlos Bustamante's group "Verification of the Crooks fluctuation theorem and recovery of RNA folding free energies". There are also the related papers by Jarzynski and Evans in which they prove their respective fluctuation theorems.

Unfortunately I don't have much in the fields that you're interested in.